# How do I define a class wide variable within a function with an arbitrary name?

Tags: c++

I am playing around with building my own list class. I don't want to use vectors in building the new list function. I think I can simply create arrays with arbitrary names, and the last array created will be stored in lastone. Then by using the data structure {reference,data}, I can scale through the list quickly by using the reference, making the name of the variable completely irrelevant.

The main question being, how exactly do I define a class wide variable within a function with an arbitrary name?

Secondary Question: In order for this to work, I realized that I will need to not actually define a specific type for anything in this class, so how would I create my own type in templates that is treated as a type throughout the entire class.

```
class PycList {
public:
    void addElement(int j);
    void defineClassVariable(int j);
private:
    int& lastone;

};
void PycList::addElement(int j) {

}
void PycList::defineClassVariable(int j) {
    //create code that will make a class wide variable with a useless name
}
```

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do such a thing? Why is vector bad? What are your trying to accomplish. (Your questions can be answered by googling templates, so its probably a bad question for StackOverflow.

Comment: "how exactly do I define a class wide variable within a function with an arbitrary name?" this sounds like an X/Y problem. Why do you think you need this and what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: I was interested - no other reason, no purpose, just something to do.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much "You can't", if you mean add members to the class itself. C++ is not a language where you can add stuff to structs or classes at runtime.

I would use a `std::map<int, int>` (assuming your "variable" is storing an integer, and uses an integer as the identififation) to define storage for your variables.

(Of course, you could use `std::vector<int>` if the numbers are "close together" and start at zero or near zero).